# Datatables multiple custom toolbar elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm adding [custom toolbar elements](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html) to a Datatables table, but I am not sure how to add more than one.

I run the JS below and it moves one element into the toolbar:

```
var elementOne = $('#elementOne');
$("div.toolbar").html(elementOne);
```

How do I add a second element to the toolbar?

I tried adding just the html of each element:

```
var elementOne = $('#elementOne');
var elementTwo = $('#elementTwo');
$("div.toolbar").html(elementOne.html() + elementTwo.html());
```

But this resulted in duplicate elements and one of them (button) did not work properly. However, I could probably fix this but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Also, I cannot generate one of the elements within JavaScript. It must be either moved, which I'd prefer, or copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use the `append` JQuery method:

```
var elementOne = $('#elementOne');
var elementTwo = $('#elementTwo');
$("div.toolbar").append(elementOne);
$("div.toolbar").append(elementTwo);
```